# Is it possible to change IBM Cloud plan of existing Database?

Tags: db2, ibm-cloud

Is it possible to change IBM Cloud plan of existing Database ?

I am expecting to change the current standard plan to elite plan as its available in Dallas region.

Comment: AFAIK, you can scale a deployed instance, but not easily change the plan. Your best bet is to contact support and chat with them.

Comment: Thanks for the revert. I chatted with the support. They mentioned its not possible to degrade a plan. The only option is to create a lite plan and migrate the data to it. Thanks for your help